# Devise Admin changes attribute of different user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, admin

I'm handling users with Devise. One user has the attribute `:admin` and the admin should be able to increase the rank of a nonadmin user.

I got following method in the controller:

```
def rank_up
  if current_user.admin?
    user.rank = user.rank + 1
  end
end
```

and this in the view:

```
- @user.each do |user|
  = user.name
  = user.rank
```

Now I want to add a link, that calls the `rank_up` method in the controller, but how does the method know which `user` should be changed?
I guess it has to do something with the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed has something to do with routes :)

Something along the following lines would do:

```
# controller
def rank_up
  user = User.find(params[:user_id]) # find by the `user_id` you pass in link_to
  user.rank_up # call model's method
  redirect_to(:back,notice: 'User hash been ranked up')
end

# routes.rb
resources :users do
  get :rank_up, on: :member # add a route for this action
end

# view
link_to 'Rank this user up', rank_up_user_path(user_id: user.id) # user from the `each` loop
```